# Flex ButtonBar inside a ListItemRenderer freeze the application?

Tags: apache-flex, itemrenderer

I have drop on a strange occurance - inserting a ButtonBar inside ListItemRenderer freeze the application. The bug is highly reproductive.

- If anyone know a workarround - it will be more than appreciated :)

here is a bit of the code :

```
<s:VGroup id="buttonHolder" visible="false" gap="0" width="100%">
        <s:ButtonBar id="buttonMenu" width="100%" height="18" minWidth="100" change="buttonMenuChangeHandler(event)">
            <s:dataProvider>
                <s:ArrayList>
                    <fx:Object label="rename"  icon="@Embed(source='assets/images/rename.png')"/>
                    <fx:Object label="delete"     icon="@Embed(source='assets/images/delete.png')"/>
                    <fx:Object label="group +" icon="@Embed(source='assets/images/group_pluss.png')"/>  
                </s:ArrayList>
            </s:dataProvider>
        </s:ButtonBar>
    </s:VGroup>
</s:VGroup>
```

Comment: Is that a Spark or an mx List you're using this ListItemRenderer in?

Comment: Your question referens to the ListItemRenderer class; but your code does not.  Please provide the full code.

Comment: it is inside Spark Tree ( http://kachurovskiy.com/2010/spark-tree/ ). (Flex 4.5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That 'Spark Tree' is based on Spark List, but ListItemRenderer is an mx component. Just don't mix those two. Use the Spark ItemRenderer instead.

The Spark and mx components have a completely different architecture, so try and avoid mixing them together, especially with such coupled components as Lists and their ItemRenderers. If you decide to go for the Spark component set, use it as extensively as you possibly can, except where there is no other way (like AdvancedDataGrid for instance). I suppose this was your intent in the first place, since you don't seem to want to use mx:Tree.

Comment: mx:Tree is so buggy, that every attempt to extend a bit more the tree nodes leading to a bug from which there is no way arround. :|. so i left without an options and went to Spark Tree. :|

Comment: Yordan, a friend of mine posted his [spark flex tree](https://github.com/wasbridge/flex-4-tree) on github yesterday.  I haven't had a chance to use it yet.

Comment: I am closing the topic ( reason: constanly decreasing accept rating :| ) since there is only a point toward incompatibility between Spark and MX. Anyway if someone know a better way to go with it - let post here. to reopen it.

Comment: @Yordan It's quite unclear what you're trying to achieve. The code you provided works flawlessly if you put it in a Spark ItemRenderer and assign it to a Spark List. Is there any reason why you absolutely want to use mx:ListItemRenderer? If the bug is produced when using the ItemRenderer in your Tree class and not in the List class, then it's a bug in that Tree class (you could try the one @J_A_X referred to).

Comment: There is working well for a bit of time, after - it freeze the application. It is happening random, and there is nothing else which is working aside of it. Just start to click fast, rotate a bit the components inside the treerenderer and it will happend, but it is random.

Comment: I can but repeat: if you're already using the Spark ItemRenderer class, it's highly probably a bug in that Tree component. Do remember that this is not a component released by Adobe and it may very well not be tested for all use cases.